# Height as a function of time word problem

Tags: word-problem

A reflector is fastened to the front wheel of a bicycle 20 cm from the center of the wheel. The diameter of the wheel and inflated tire is 70 cm. If the bike is traveling at 10 km/h, express the height of the reflector above the ground as a fuction of time. Assume that at time t = 0 seconds, the reflector is at its highest point.

Comment: Identify the relevant variables, assign symbols to them.  Then write down all the formulas you know involving them that might be relevant.  Edit your question to include your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:-***

Speed of bicycle wheel=${\frac {10^6}{3600}}$cm/s.

Circumference of wheel=$220\space cm$.

Now,calculate number of revolutions in $1 sec$ at the above given speed.

Now,express this as a function of time (in sec).